# Rviz is not updating /joint_states

Tags: mapping, simulation, ros, gazebo-simu, rviz

I have a custom URDF mobile robot. The robot is moving in the gazebo by `/cmd_vel` but the wheel of the robot is not moving in Rviz. The robot is spilling over the surface in Rviz.[image]

here is the `joint_info.yaml`

```yaml
my_robot: 
  joint_state_controller:
    type: joint_state_controller/JointStateController
    publish_rate: 50
```

and this is `robot.launch` file

```xml
<launch>
  <param name="robot_description" textfile="$(find my_robot)/urdf/my_robot.urdf"/>
  <arg name="world_file" default="$(find my_robot)/world/Untitled/model2.world"/>
  <include file="$(find gazebo_ros)/launch/empty_world.launch">
    <arg name="world_name" value="$(arg world_file)"/>
  </include>
  

<!-- Spawn custom robot the URDF -->
  <node
    name="spawn_model"
    pkg="gazebo_ros"
    type="spawn_model"
    args="-file $(find my_robot)/urdf/my_robot.urdf -urdf -model my_robot"
    output="screen" />

  <node pkg="robot_state_publisher" type="robot_state_publisher" name="robot_state_publisher" >
      <param name="use_sim_time" value="false"/>
</node>

<!-- Publishing joint state  -->
<node pkg="joint_state_publisher" type="joint_state_publisher" name="joint_state_publisher" >
  <remap from="joint_state_publisher" to ="joint_states" />
</node>

<!-- Joint COnfiguration yaml file -->
<rosparam file="$(find my_robot)/config/joint_info.yaml" command="load"/>
<node name="my_robot" pkg="controller_manager" type="spawner" respawn="false" output="screen" args="joint_state_controller"/>

<!-- Gmapping  -->
<node pkg="gmapping" type="slam_gmapping" name="slam_gmapping" output="screen" >
  <remap from="scan" to="scan"/>
</node>

<!-- open Rviz -->
  <node name="rviz" pkg="rviz" type="rviz" args="-d $(find my_robot)/rviz/robot.rviz" />

</launch>
```

when I check the `/joint_states` by `rostopic echo /joint_states` the joint states where not updating here is the image[image]. `wheel_j1` `wheel_j2` `wheel_j3` `wheel_j4` is not updating. How can I fix it?

Comment: which plugins do you have in your URDF?

Comment: You can take a look at this [steer bot repo](https://github.com/srmainwaring/steer_bot) and check which plugins are used

Comment: I am using the `differential_drive_controller` plugin provided by Gazebo [Plugin](https://classic.gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=ros_gzplugins)

Comment: shouldn't that be publishing the `joint_states` if done properly? I think you shouldn't start another `joint_state_publisher`

Comment: if I don't launch the `joint_state_publisher` in launch file. then the wheel get disapper in Rviz

Comment: in that case, do yu have any topic publishing the `/joint_states`?

Comment: No, In this case `/joint_states` is  not publishing any data